# Laravel CLI has stopped working after inserting data into database

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to insert data into a database. This actually works but whenever the submit button is clicked and the browser goes to the action page, i get a "CLI has stopped working" error resulting in a shut down of the local php server.

[image]

Since i have no clue as to why i am getting this problem. I will provide all the code that possibly could lead to this error.

The form:

```
<form method="POST" action="store">
{{ csrf_field() }}
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" id="title" name="title">
    <label for="url">URL</label>
    <input type="text" id="url" name="url">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Article;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AddArticle extends Controller
{
...
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $article = new Article;
        $article->title = $request->title;
        $article->url = $request->url;
        $article->save();
    }
...
```

The model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{
    protected $table = "posts";
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'url',
    ];
}
```

The web.php route:

```
Route::post('/store', 'AddArticle@store');
```

When the browser goes to /store, i get this CLI stopped working error.

Kind regards

Comment: PHP and windows versions? FYI Usually tied to opcache

Comment: PHP 7.1.9 and windows 8

Comment: You can try get more information at windows Event Viewer

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69233 https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73983 possible candidates. Quick fix might be to disable opcache. But could be something else, as said check logs.

Comment: is the syntax to insert the data correct?

Comment: Are you using the Laravel Artisan development server? If not, try and see if that works, you can call the command `php artisan serve` in your project directory to start the server.

Comment: @AwesomeGuy No, i was using `php -S localhost:8888 -t public` to start the local php server.